# Implementing isPrime in Scala using tail recursion

Tags: algorithm, scala, primes

I'm working on an exercise which requires me to implement isPrime in scala using tail recursion. I do have an implementation however, I'm having issues with producing the right base case.

So my algorithm involves checking all numbers from 2 to N/2, since N/2 would be the largest factor of N.

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = {
    def isPrimeUntil(t: Int): Boolean = {
        if(t == 2) true
        else n % t != 0 && isPrimeUntil(t - 1)
    }

    isPrimeUntil(n/2)
}
```

So basically if I want to check if 15 is a prime I will check all numbers from 7 to 2.

Here is my trace:

`isPrimeUntil(7) -> true && isPrimeUntil(6)`
`-> true && isPrimeUntil(5)`
`-> false && isPrimeUntil(4)`

Because of short-circuit evaluation, the function returns false at this point.

However, my implementation fails for the basic case of checking if 3 is prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 isn't your only problem. It also returns `true` for `4` ... 
Your base case should be `1`, not `2`:

```
   def isPrimeUntil(t: Int): Boolean = t == 1 || t > 1 && n%t != 0 && isPrimeUntil(t-1)
```

Comment: I would change it to `t == 1 || t > 1 && ...` to handle one and zero, which are not prime (nor composite).

Comment: Yeah, good point ... Also cuts off negative numbers (which can't be prime either).

Answer (score 1):

Although Krzystof correctly pointed that the source of the problem is integer division, I don't like his solution. I believe that the proper fix is change the test to

```
 if(t <= 2) true
```

With such check in the case of `n = 3` and so `n/2 = 1` it will stop without going to `t = 0`.

Some benefits:

- The modified check `(t <= 2)` on almost any modern hardware is as efficient as the check for `(t == 2)`
- IMHO it better conveys the logic
- It is very inefficient way to write `(n.toDouble/2).ceil.toInt` that way. It's easier and faster to write `(n+1)/2` instead of doing 2 conversion (to double and back to int)
- It doesn't require an excessive check for all odd `n` (`(n+1)/2` is never the smallest divisor for an odd `n` where there is a difference between `n/2` and `ceil(n/2)`)